# live sandbox containing multiple apis

Tags: api, rest

I remember once seeing a site that contained all the popular apis and it displayed sample data when you fetched or inserted content via REST. I cant remember what site it was on so if anyone knows let me know thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably looking for [this](https://apigee.com/providers).

Answer (score 0):

This [site](http://www.programmableweb.com/apis/directory/1?protocol=REST) is a directory to all API Services provided by companies.

Comment: thanks, but i was looking for apigee.com its a testing playground